# custom cell format or mask (GPS coordinates) in phpExcel?

Tags: gps, format, phpexcel, masking

I'm trying to figure out how to use a custom cell format or create an input mask so users can enter data (32° 12' 13.44", 32° 12' 13.4" or 32° 12' 13") and not allow other formats, this is to avoid mistakes and because the application that processes the information needs the symbols (°, ', ") to distinguish each bit of the GPS coordinate.

I read [this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/529038) and tried it:

```
#NumberFormat.php
const FORMAT_GPS                        = '##°##\'##.##\"';
```

Controller:

```
 $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1', '32° 12\' 13.44"')
                    ->setCellValue('B1', '32° 12\' 13.4"')
                    ->setCellValue('C1', '32° 12\' 13"');
            $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C2')->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray(
                    array(
                        'code' => \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GPS
                    )
            );
```

Note: I don't think it's correct...

However although it does show the format when clicking 'Format cells' it doesn't do anything when values that don't match the format are entered by the user.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Comment: Try and work out the mask you'd need to use in MS Excel first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Excel, I can use a mask something like:

```
##0"°"00"'"00\"
```

Perhaps something like

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Masked')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Degrees')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Minutes')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Seconds')
    ->setCellValue('E1', 'Decimal');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A2', 532128.8864)
    ->setCellValue('B2', '=FLOOR(A2/10000,SIGN(A2))')
    ->setCellValue('C2', '=MOD(FLOOR(ABS(A2)/100,1),100)')
    ->setCellValue('D2', '=MOD(ABS(A2),100)')
    ->setCellValue('E2', '=(ABS(B2)+C2/60+D2/3600)*SIGN(A2)')
    ->setCellValue('F2', 'Latitude');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A3', -21625.3338)
    ->setCellValue('B3', '=FLOOR(A3/10000,SIGN(A3))')
    ->setCellValue('C3', '=MOD(FLOOR(ABS(A3)/100,1),100)')
    ->setCellValue('D3', '=MOD(ABS(A3),100)')
    ->setCellValue('E3', '=(ABS(B3)+C3/60+D3/3600)*SIGN(A3)')
    ->setCellValue('F3', 'Longitude');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A2:A3')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('##0"°"00"\'"00\"');
```

(Tested while waiting in Manchester airport)

Comment: very kind of you sr. Thank you very much for helping me.